# Display list of active (running) applications in a list view

Tags: android

I am trying to write an application that displays the list of running applications. I used activity manager for that. While running the application, It is showing the following error."UNHANDLED EVENT LOOP EXECUTION" IN ERROR LOG and application is force closing.

Please help me to find my mistake.
My code is given below.

```
public class ActiveApplicationsActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        String[] sl = (String[]) l.toArray();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sl);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am adding the logcat information

```
02-01 10:52:47.790: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM  
02-01 10:52:47.790: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo   {com.msat.sd102268.taskmanager.activeapplications/com.msat.sd102268.taskmanager.activeapplications.ActiveApplicationsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.msat.sd102268.taskmanager.activeapplications.ActiveApplicationsActivity.onCreate(ActiveApplicationsActivity.java:23)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)  
02-01 10:52:47.811: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: please check the log cat and check at which line you are getting the error.... ????

Comment: there is no line number specified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] sl = (String[]) l.toArray();
```

You simply cannot convert a `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` into a `String`

try this

```
String[] sl = new String[l.size()];
int i = 0;
for(RunningAppProcessInfo info : l)
 sl[i++] = info.getProcessName();// fictional function
```

or use a `List` itself

Comment: how should i use list in ArrayAdapter directly? Please tell me.

Comment: Ya..what you said is right..i can't use list in arrayadapter directly..I extracted the information such as processName, processId, etc using l.get(i).processName & l.get(i).pid respectively. I then used a custom ListAdapter to display those values..thanks for your help..you gave me an idea of how to extract those values..!!